# How can I display a pointer address in C#?

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

I've not done any pointers since I've been programming in C# - and my C++ days were long ago.  I thought I should refresh my knowledge and was just playing around with them because of another question on here.  I understand them all okay, but I can't figure out how to write the pointer's address to the console...

```
char c = 'c';
char d = 'd';
char e = 'e';

unsafe
{
    char* cp = &d;
    //How do I write the pointer address to the console?
    *cp = 'f';
    cp = &e;
    //How do I write the pointer address to the console?
    *cp = 'g';
    cp = &c;
    //How do I write the pointer address to the console?
    *cp = 'h';        
}
Console.WriteLine("c:{0}", c); //should display "c:h";
Console.WriteLine("d:{0}", d); //should display "d:f";
Console.WriteLine("e:{0}", e); //should display "e:g";
```

Using `Console.WriteLine(*cp);` gives me the current value at the pointer address... what if I want to display the actual address?

Comment: Not tried it but what does Console.WriteLine(cp); give you?

Comment: @Lazarus - You don't think that was the first thing I tried? LOL. Give me some credit, I'd already tried everything obvious before I came asking questions on here ;)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(new IntPtr(cp));
```

Answer (score 4):

Remember that with managed code the garbage collector is free to move things around on you.  Make sure to *pin* your object down if your in a situation where the address matters.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* cptr;
char achr = 'a';
cptr = &achr;
string strcptr = Convert.ToString((long)cptr, 16);
Console.WriteLine("Ox{0} is the char ptr hex address", strcptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char c = 'c';

unsafe
{
  Console.WriteLine("0x{0:x}", (ulong)&c);
  Console.WriteLine($"0x{(ulong)&c:x}");
}
```

This will display something like ... 0x123abc (twice)

Answer (score 0):

Convert your pointer to byte type.